# Check if website is displayed on TV?

Tags: javascript, css

If I'm watching my website on my PS4 browser on my TV, the text is very small (probably because the tv is 1920x1080) - but I actually want it to format, as if it was on mobile (filling the whole screen to be readable from my sofa).

Is there a way to check if the website is displayed on a tv-screen?

(It could be through chromecast as well)

Comment: look into css media queries

Comment: You can do this with `@media` queries. With those you can set different rules for different resolutions.

Comment: A related SO post http://stackoverflow.com/q/17777272/1793718

Comment: @Xufox The resolution of my tv is the exact same as my computer monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for a special user agent in your TV's browser by going to a page like this (http://mybrowserinfo.com/detail.asp).

Then you can use the `data-useragent` and `data-platform` attributes to selectively apply CSS (see an example here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/add-data-attribute-of-user-agent/).